# how to implement search for DAM ECL connector?

Tags: sites-9.1, ecl-connector

there is one sites 9.1 tridion customer for whom we have DAM connector implementation. now the requirement is that we need to implement search box for that ecl connector.

i have searched online but did not find much help.
if anybody has any experience or knowledge then it will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.V2 you can achieve search implementing methods

- public bool CanSearch(int publicationId)
- public IFolderContent Search(IEclUri contextUri, string searchTerm, int pageIndex, int numberOfItems)

these are methods from Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.V2.IContentLibraryContext interface

Comment: thank you for the quick response. let me try this.